# Change Firefox's Already Remembered Proxy Username and Password

Tags: firefox, proxy

Personal Squid proxy server deployed in the cloud. Had it configured and working but have since changed the username and password (it was 'user' & 'test'). But now Firefox isn't prompting me (like before) for a username and password when I connect to the proxy and I'm getting a 'Proxy refused connection' error (which makes sense). So I need to update my username and password in Firefox to the more secure one. Like a dummy, I checked the 'remember username and password' box on the login prompt and now it won't pop up anymore. I believe that the proxy server is configured correctly, because I used to be able to connect, and still can on Firefox Ubuntu, but not on Windows.

I have looked for username info in Firefox settings, but can't find it.
I have change the about:config setting 'signon.autologin.proxy' to 'false' in firefox, restart firefox, restarted the computer, and restarted the server. Still no luck.
I have checked the 'Passwords' section of Firefox, but the username-password is not saved there.
I have turned off the 'Do not prompt for authentication if password is saved' in Connection Settings.

I can't find hardly anything related to changing this username and password anywhere on the internet. Does anybody know how to change these settings in Firefox without uninstalling and reinstalling the browser?

Thanks for you time.